# Render HTML inside p tag using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm running into some trouble and wanted to see if someone could help out - Is it possible to render HTML inside a p tag within a .vue file?

Here is the HTML portion:

```html
<div class="content" :id="post['GUID']" ref="snapshot">
  <p id="summary">{{ post['Summary'] }}</p>
</div>
```

I am trying to render the `post['Summary']` as HTML, but the summary is being displayed as this in string format:

```html
<div class="ExternalClass394D5102B42B4570882C28EA620584C8"><div style="font-family&#58;Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size&#58;11pt;color&#58;rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span style="color&#58;black;">​<p style="margin&#58;0in;font-size&#58;12pt;font-family&#58;&quot;Times New Roman&quot;, serif;"><i><span style="font-family&#58;&quot;Whitney Medium&quot;;color&#58;black;">Upping Your Game!</span></i>
```

In a .vue file, how can I render the HTML tag inside the p?

Comment: This is the reason why v-html exists. It's unsafe and shouldn't be used for user content. It's unknown from the question where data comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) to bind HTML variables:

```html
<p id="summary" v-html="post['Summary']"></p>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    post: {
      Summary: `<div class="ExternalClass394D5102B42B4570882C28EA620584C8"><div style="font-family&#58;Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size&#58;11pt;color&#58;rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span style="color&#58;black;">​<p style="margin&#58;0in;font-size&#58;12pt;font-family&#58;&quot;Times New Roman&quot;, serif;"><i><span style="font-family&#58;&quot;Whitney Medium&quot;;color&#58;black;">Upping Your Game!</span></i>`
    }
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-html="post.Summary"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to only extract the <p> tags inside v-html?

Comment: No. You'd have to parse the HTML yourself for that.